# How to list only ordinary files on UNIX

Tags: linux, unix, ls, gnu

I'd like to list only ordinary files (not directories or symlinks) using ls from GNU tools. So far I have only some hackish greps. Is there an option or better way of doing that?

Edit: I need more coffee: `find -type d`

Thanks

Comment: Ok I guess I need to use `find` and I am done :-)

Comment: Please post it as an answer and accept it once you can to mark this question solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried with find type -f. I mean

```
find /path/of/yourlocation type -f
```

Answer (score 2):

As you didn't specify your shell, here is a solution using the Z shell. Using `zsh` it is very easy to restrict *any* command to only plain files:

```
zsh% ls *(.)
zsh% tail *(.)
```

This uses the so called *Glob Qualifier* `(.)` to restricts the expansion of `*` to only plain files. See `man zshexpn` for much more qualifiers and explanations. Using *Glob Qualifier* I nearly never need monstrous `find` calls anymore.